# Existe um meio de nomear as tabelas selecionadas de uma stored procedure para identificá-las no DataSet?

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Possuo uma Store Procedure no SQL Server que projeta vários dados. Exemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[teste_sp]
AS
BEGIN    

  select * from compra
  select * from cliente
  select * from fatura

END
```

Porém, ao recuperar o DataSet no C#, os nomes das tabelas são mostrados como: "Table1", "Table2" e "Table3".

Existe alguma forma de nomear essas tabelas dinamicamente?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com nomear DINAMICAMENTE?

Comment: Eu posso setar manualmente no c# o nome das tabelas (`DataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "Nome"`), mas eu procuro uma forma de nomear essas tabelas dentro da procedure. Assim eu posso recuperar as tabelas pelo nome e não só pelo índice.

Comment: Como você faz pra trazer os dados no C#?

Comment: Eu uso `using (SqlDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` e carrego as tabelas fazendo uma iteração: `while (!reader.IsClosed) { dt.Load(reader); ds.Tables.Add(dt); }`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar conjuntos de `datasets` ou `tablemapping`

algo assim.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(...);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTableMapping dtm1, dtm2, dtm3;
dtm1 = da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "compra"); 
dtm2 = da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "cliente");
dtm3 = da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "fatura");
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Ainda não resolve o problema, pois preciso que ela já venham nomeadas do SQL.